# Why 'toFillForm' not work in jest-puppeteer?

Tags: forms, click, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to fill a form in a profile view.
The problem is when I clear the inputs, this action does not work.

The function `toFillForm` click on inputs 3 times, or select all of the words in the input.

In my case, it doesn't replace, it just overwrites.

```js
await expect(page).toFillForm('form', {
   givenname: 'new name',
   surname: ' '
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The toFillForm function uses the toFill function which triple clicks on an element to replace the text that was in the field and has a delay while it is typing. It targets inputs where `[name="givenname"]` and `[name="surname"]` per your provided code. In my understanding, replacing the text in an input is the same as overwriting it. Could you further clarify and/or provide code for the form you are trying to test?